# Methods Do Not Reference Each Other

Tags: java, methods, class-method

I am just getting introduced to methods in my MIS class, and I am having some trouble integrating the methods to work together. I need to create 3 separate methods that control the code. The object is to be able to either count the number of words in a sentence, or count the number of vowels in a word, the way that you switch between the methods is inputting a v, w, or q to quit. My code only spits out input from the main method, and I need it to reference the other methods to work properly. I don't know how to reference the other methods in my code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot guys!

The top method is my main method, the middle one is my word counting method, and the third is my vowel method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P7_MethodTester
{
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    System.out.println("Enter v to count vowels, w to count words, and q to quit");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    String str = in.next();
    while(str != "q")
    {
    if(str.equals("w")){
        System.out.println("Please input your sentence: ");
        String w = in.next();

        System.out.println("You input " + countWords(str) + " words");
    }
    else if(str.equals("v")){
       System.out.println("Please input your sentence: ");
        String v = in.next();
        System.out.println("You input " + countVowels(str) + "vowels");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Program terminated");
    }
}
}

public static int countWords(String w){

    int wordCount = 0;

    boolean word = false;
    int endOfLine = w.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(w.charAt(i)) && i != endOfLine) {
            word = true;
        } else if (!Character.isLetter(w.charAt(i)) && word) {
            wordCount++;
            word = false;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(w.charAt(i)) && i == endOfLine) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}

public static int countVowels(String v){
    int vowels_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length(); i++) {
        char current_char = Character.toLowerCase(v.charAt(i));
        if (current_char == 'a' || current_char == 'e' || current_char == 'o'
        || current_char == 'i' || current_char == 'u' || current_char == 'y') {
            vowels_count += 1;
        }
    }
    return vowels_count;
}

}
```

Comment: You tagged this question with javascript. Java and JavaScript are not the same. It's a common mistake.

Comment: You are passing `w` or `q` or ... as params instead of `sentence` entered.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the countWords and countVowels function with 'w' and 'v' you have passed str for both the functions

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that come to question. Like do you want to evaluate the sentence as "w" or "q" or "v"

I suggest you instantiate a `new Scanner` after the first.

```
while (!str.equals("q")) {
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This way you represent 2 entries. I would probably not use `while`.

Also, look into using `Scanner.nextLine()` for the whole sentence.

And finally, pass `w` or `v` not `str` as arguments to `countWords` and `countVowels`.

You should think of the program as steps:

1. ask action
2. get sentence
3. perform action
4. and repeat or exit.

Comment: I take that back. I would use `while` but for recursive method call purposes.